# Tableau Online vs Tableau Server

Tags: tableau-api

We currently use Tableau Online. I am wondering if there are differences from Tableau Server as in cost per year, report sharing and performance.

Comment: I recommend doing a bit more research before asking a question. This question is a bit broad. Tableau has changed their pricing to a subscription bases early in 2018 so I recommend contacted them for that question. As for sharing reports, there is no difference. Report performance depends on the server's hardware specifications and entirely how many people are using. Tableau Server and Tableau Online is the same thing, only difference is Tableau Online is their server is maintained and managed by them.

Comment: I use Tableau Online and have encountered several limitations which I understand I could work around by using Tableau on premise. As @Dip suggestions, I would do a lot more research into this and your specific use cases.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a link to up-to-date Tableau pricing:

https://www.tableau.com/pricing/teams-orgs

"On Premise and Public cloud" refers to Tableau Server and "Fully hosted by Tableau" refers to Tableau Online

Tableau Server licensing cost is less than Tableau Online but with Tableau Online you don't have to purchase or maintain the infrastructure (server) which hosts the software. In my opinion Tableau Online is generally more cost effective for smaller scale solutions and any upgrades are managed by Tableau whereas Tableau Server is generally better if you want to keep all your data on premise or for larger solutions.

I don't think there is any difference in terms of sharing reports.

Performance wise, Tableau Online runs on a shared infrastructure whereas you can choose the spec of the server you run Tableau Server on. If performance is a concern, then you have more flexibility with Tableau Server and you can usually situate the server closer to the data source and spec the server as high as you need.

Another link which might be of interest: https://interworks.com/blog/bfair/2014/08/26/tableau-online-vs-tableau-server-5-things-consider/